# Can I get the size of a future transaction from Blockchain.info API?

Tags: blockchain.info

Let's say I want to send 1 XBT to another address, from my own `Blockchain.info` wallet. When I try to do this transaction from the website of `Blockchain.info` it states the recomended transaction fee I should provide along the transaction.

But what if I would like to make this transaction happen programmatically, using the `Blockchain.info API`? I know that transaction fee depends on the size in bytes of the transaction that is happening. I also have a reliable information of the satoshi/byte needed for the transaction to happen in a timely manner. But is there any possible way, to get the size of the transaction, BEFORE I actually send it out using the `Blockchain.info API`?